# Histogram over non-integral buckets

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get a histogram plot for data that has been collected in buckets that are portions of [0,1].  That is, I collect counts of values that fall into [0, 0.05), [0.05, 0.1), [0.1, 0.15), etc.  The data is collected in an list, where each element of the list contains counts for each bucket so far.

I don't use the `histogram` function; I don't see how to use that in a convenient way with data collected in a list, from many ticks.  Instead, I've been doing this:

```
let x 0
foreach normalized-buckets [
  plotxy x ?
  ;set x x + bucket-size
  set x x + 1
]
```

There are no plotting commands in the pen box in the UI.  I've listed two versions of the line that increments the x coordinate.

(1) What I would prefer to use is the line that's commented out.  I would like the plot to display 1 as the max value in the plot's lower right corner, with a narrow bars as in a normal histogram.  Instead, what I get are overlapping bars that start at the x coordinate `x`, and end at 1.

If you have advice about how to do this, there may be no need to read the rest of my question.

---

(2) The only way I've found to get a normal histogram effect is to plot at integer values, i.e. using the second `set x` line.  This has two problems, but it may be the best solution.

First, using this method, the plot displays a max value other than 1 in the lower right corner, when it works, since I'm plotting values at integers 1-20 rather than at 0, 0.05, etc.

Second, I can't figure out how to get the plot to use 20 as the max value, or even 21.  The problem is that no matter what I do, I can get 20 histogram bars only if I choose `auto-scale` on for the plot.  For buckets of size 0.05, i.e. 20 buckets, the result is that the max value displayed on the lower left corner of the plot is then 22.5, and there's a space to the right of the bars.  This looks crude, though it works.

I've tried using `set-histogram-num-bars` and `set-plot-x-range` in various ways without `auto-scale`, both in the plot setup commands window, and in my `setup` routine.  No matter what I do, once the plotting begins, the max value reverts to 1.  (This happens with either of the `set x` lines above.  With `set x x + 1`, only a line at y=0 is displayed--presumably because I have no data in the first bucket most of the time.)

So I can get a workable histogram, but only with a max value displayed as 22.5, and with a space to the right of the bars.

Comment: There is a histogram in networks / preferential attachment example (models library) - see the log-log histogram (custom defined buckets).

Comment: Thanks @bergant.  It was useful to look at that.  It turns out that it uses points instead of bars.  If you switch it to bars, shows exactly the same problem described in my option (1).  That this is what's done in a Models Library example suggests that there's no solution that solves option 1 (without writing an extension).   If so, OK, but I'd still wonder what's going wrong with option (2).  Possibly I need to post an MWE for that one, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the bar width directly using `set-plot-pen-interval`.

Comment: Thanks Seth.  It looked to me like `set-plot-pen-interval` affects the `histogram` command, but didn't have an effect with `plotxy` and plot-pen-mode set to bar.  But I just got it to work by editing the guts of the pen NetLogo code in Preferential Attachment.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out.  I call `clear-plot` on every tick.  I have to add `set-plot-pen-interval` after that.  Thank you.  I didn't think this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that NetLogo's plotting system doesn't support creating bar graphs where the bars have different widths — unless you fake it by using line mode, not bar mode, and then draw the bars yourself using `plotxy`, one line segment at a time. This is a bit difficult, but not terrible.

I'm getting lost trying to follow (2) just from your verbal description. It would help if you included the exact code that is giving the incorrect result, and also included a screen shot of the incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't clear.  I don't want variable-width bars.  I just want uniform-width bars representing values at 0, 0.05, 0.10, ... 0.95, with the x range displayed as going from 0 to 1.  So the first bar would appear to go from 0 to 0.05, the second would appear to go from 0.05 to 0.1, etc.  However, what happens if I try to do this, is that I in fact get variable-width bars.  Every bar extends from its starting point to 1.  I'll post more info about (2).  I'll try to construct a simple case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Correction: It appears that NetLogo wants to give every bar width 1.  If the x range has max 1 and is not auto-scaled, and values are plotted at fractional x values, then bars will have different widths because they start at different values and all stop at 1.  If the range is auto-scaled, then you get fixed-width but overlapping bars if they're plotted at nearby fractional values.  (e.g. this happens if you set the pen to bars in the log-log plot in Preferential Attachment in the Models Lib.)  What would be ideal would be to change bar width depending on x range and histogram-num-bars.

Comment: See my other answer, then.